# Return the column name of the second largest value of a row

Tags: r, rowwise

```
df = data.frame( ID = c (1,2,3,4,5), a = c (0,2,0,1,0),
                 b = c (0,3,2,NA,0), c = c(0,4,NA,NA,1),
                 d = c (2,5,4,NA,1))
maxn <- function(n) function(x) order(x, decreasing = TRUE)[n]
df<-df %>% mutate( second_largest=apply(.[2:5], 1, function(x) names(x)[maxn(2)(x)]) )
```

I used the R codes above to obtain the column name for the second largest value of a,b,c,d. For ID=4, because there are missing values for b,c,d, so the name of second largest value should be `NA`. However, the codes return b. How should I remove missing value?

Comment: What if there are two `1`s and two `0`s?

Comment: I'll select from left to right

Comment: Then what would be your choice? between two `1`s you take one for max one for second largest or no you just take both for max?

Comment: If both two 1 in the 1st and 2nd column, the max one should be the 2nd column, and the second largest one should be the 1st column. The left variable would be the smaller one. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one more approach

```r
df = data.frame( ID = c (1,2,3,4,5), a = c (0,2,0,1,0),
                 b = c (0,3,2,NA,0), c = c(0,4,NA,NA,1),
                 d = c (2,5,4,NA,1))

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(name = {x <- c_across(everything());
  if (sum(!is.na(x)) >= 2) tail(head(names(cur_data())[order(x, decreasing = T)],2),1) else NA})

#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#> # Rowwise:  ID
#>      ID     a     b     c     d name 
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1     0     0     0     2 a    
#> 2     2     2     3     4     5 c    
#> 3     3     0     2    NA     4 b    
#> 4     4     1    NA    NA    NA <NA> 
#> 5     5     0     0     1     1 d
```

---

If you have to do it for a few columns instead

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(name = {x <- c_across(c('a', 'c'));
  if (sum(!is.na(x)) >= 2) tail(head(c('a', 'c')[order(x, decreasing = T)],2),1) else NA})

# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Rowwise:  ID
     ID     a     b     c     d name 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     0     0     0     2 c    
2     2     2     3     4     5 a    
3     3     0     2    NA     4 NA   
4     4     1    NA    NA    NA NA   
5     5     0     0     1     1 a
```

Comment: How do I limit to data only from 2nd column to 4rd column if there are many columns in my dataset?

Comment: @NewYorkCrosser, please tell whether I am understanding you correctly, because I got confused after seeing different answers

Comment: Yes, the codes return what I want! I just want to know how I can limit the analysis to selected columns. Thank you very much.

Comment: @NewYorkCrosser, yes there are many ways to limit the search.  these ways depend upon the actual names of cols.  You can use selection helper functions instead of `everything()`

Comment: @NewYorkCrosser, please tell me your actual column names so that I can suggest you something

Comment: For example, I want to limit to 3 columns named "A", "B", "C", or from 3rd column to 5th column ([, 3:5]). Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233932/discussion-between-new-york-crosser-and-anilgoyal).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the following solution. I tested some possible configurations of numbers and it worked:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(Name = pmap_chr(., ~ {x <- c(...)[-1]; 
  if(sum(is.na(x)) >= 3) {
    NA
  } else { 
    ind <- which(x == max(x[!is.na(x)]))
    if(length(ind) > 1) {
      colnames(df[-1])[ind[2]]
    } else {
      colnames(df[-1])[which(x == sort(x)[length(sort(x))-1])][1]
    }
  }
 }
))

  ID a  b  c  d Name
1  1 0  0  0  2    a
2  2 2  3  4  5    c
3  3 0  2 NA  4    b
4  4 1 NA NA NA <NA>
5  5 0  0  1  1    d
```

Answer (score 0):

We can change the function to -

```
maxn <- function(n) function(x) order(x, decreasing = TRUE)[!is.na(x)][n]
```

The code will then work with your approach -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(second_largest=apply(.[2:5], 1, function(x) names(x)[maxn(2)(x)])) 

#  ID a  b  c  d second_largest
#1  1 0  0  0  2              a
#2  2 2  3  4  5              c
#3  3 0  2 NA  4              b
#4  4 1 NA NA NA           <NA>
#5  5 0  0  1  1              d
```